# Need assistance with SQL query in changing a NUMBER ID to a name

Tags: sql

Currently in my query I have:

```
Eml.TimeSupCZ  AS 'TKC Supervisor Name'  
 FROM  Emp INNER JOIN Eml ON (Emp.Emp = Eml.Emp)
```

What I need to do is for TKC Supervisor field (EML.TIMESUPCZ) I currently have the tkc supervisor ID.

I need to change that so a NAME appears.

How do i do that? The TKC supervisor ID number is in the EMl TABLE.

Comment: Please include your database structure and any code you've tried so far.

Comment: Sounds like you need to join to the emp table twice once for the supervisor name once for other name.

Answer (score 0):

change Eml.TimeSupCZ to the name of the column where the name is saved instead of the ID number